# How can I automatically invite new enterprise members to a specific folder as collaborator?

Tags: box-api, box

There's one special folder that I need everyone as collaborators. I can add all existing members but would like it be automatically done for all future new members. 
I know I could write an app using Box API to check for new members and then add collaboration through API, but just want to know if there's a simpler solution - just create a folder and apply some settings, then new members could be automatically invited.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is your account enabled for single sign on? If so you can pass the group membership via SAML and assign the folder you wish all users to be collaborated on to that group.

For instance you could create an "All Users" group on Box (Admin Cosole >> Users and Groups) and then assign it your "All Users Default Folder" then pass this "All Users" group name as an attribute in your SAML assertion.

If you do not have single sign on enabled I would still recommend collaborating new users by group membership but you will need to perform two steps 
1. Create a new user
2. Add the user to the "All Users" group
These functions can both be done via the API. It just depends how you are currently provisioning seats to your Box account.

Comment: I don't have single sign on enabled. I was thinking Box might have a configuration way, not API way which could do this automatically. So, finally, I just do this one user by one user.